# Examine security policies pushed by exchange administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, exchange

Is there a way to examine the exchange security policies pushed by the exchange admin? I have outlook running with no problems, but when I go to add my exchange account to the Windows 10 Calendar app, it tells me I need to apply certain security policies. I'd like to examine what those policies are before (or after, if need be) they are applied.

Comment: [From Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/This-device-doesn-t-meet-the-security-requirements-set-by-your-email-administrator-87132fc7-2c7f-4a71-9de0-779ff81c86ca?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA): "Check with your administrator to see which policies apply to your mailbox"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 But the policy is obviously pushed to my machine eventually. I'd like to see what it is. If I have to just watch what is changed, that's fine too.

Comment: @Carrot Are you talking about Group Policies regarding Exchange or a different type of policy. To view your group policies, run rsop.msc, and through cmd run 'gpresult /scope /user /v"

Comment: Possibly Group Policies, although I'm not sure GP would apply if the computer isn't domain-joined. Can the mail/calendar apps push policies outside of GP?

Comment: Do you know what version of Exchange you are running? The defaults for Exchange 2013 are listed here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123484(v=exchg.141).aspx